# Is this SFINAE technique involving variadic templates valid?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, sfinae

libstdc++'s implementation of `std::experimental::optional` [uses](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/experimental/optional?view=markup#l166) a SFINAE technique that seems to work with gcc, but not with clang.

I've reduced it to the following minimal example:

```
// Standard enable_if class
template <bool> struct enable_if {};
template <> struct enable_if<true> { typedef int type; };

// An example trait
template <typename> struct trait { static const bool value = true; };

// Overload to call if the trait is false
template<typename T, typename enable_if<!trait<T>::value>::type...>
void foo(T);

// Overload to call if the trait is true
template<typename T, typename enable_if<trait<T>::value>::type...>
void foo(T);

// Call site
void bar() {
    foo(0);
}
```

This compiles with gcc, but not with clang. Clang's error is:

```
test.cpp:18:5: error: call to 'foo' is ambiguous
    foo(0);
    ^~~
test.cpp:11:6: note: candidate function [with T = int, $1 = <>]
void foo(T);
     ^
test.cpp:14:6: note: candidate function [with T = int, $1 = <>]
void foo(T);
     ^
```

Clearly, gcc is discarding the first overload as a candidate because it encounters a substitution failure while subtituting `T = int` into `typename enable_if<!trait<T>::value>::type`.

Clang, on the other hand, seems to skip performing that substitution, perhaps because it realizes that there are zero template arguments bound to that parameter pack. As a result, it doesn't encounter a substitution failure, and the first overload remains viable.

**Who is right?**

Comment: This looks like [PR11723](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=11723).

Comment: @user3493289: Agreed, thanks. I voted to close.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience interpreting what the C++ spec  says about template argument deduction, but I'll take a stab at this:

**gcc is right.**

`[temp.deduct] p5` says (emphasis mine):

> When all template arguments have been deduced or obtained from default
>   template arguments, **all uses** of template parameters in the template
>   parameter list of the template and the function type are replaced with
>   the corresponding deduced or default argument values. If the
>   substitution results in an invalid type, as described above, type
>   deduction fails.

The use of `T` in `typename enable_if<!trait<T>::value>::type...` is a use of a template parameter in the template parameter list of the template; since the above paragraph says that **all** such uses are replaced with the corresponding argument values, this substitution needs to be performed, in spite of the fact that no template arguments are bound to this parameter pack.